# Is it alright to have a field type of ObjectId in a mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

Let's say I will be having a many to one relationship in mongodb,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectID = Schema.Types.ObjectId;


var productSchema = new Schema({
   supplier: {
      _id: ObjectId,
      name: String
   }
});
```

I have read a mongodb blog post about [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2), and read that:

> Denormalizing only makes sense when there’s an high ratio of reads to updates. If you’ll be reading the denormalized data frequently, but updating it only rarely

Since the the `supplier` doesn't update frequently, I decided to have it's name denormalize, but still having the `_id` so when I have to update it I have something to reference.

I decided to use `ObjectId` as the `type`, but I haven't actually tested it if it works, and I already wanted to know, if I am doing it right, and if using `String` type would be more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to use an `ObjectId` there, but also define a `ref` for it to tell Mongoose which model it refers to so that you can use Mongoose's reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) when you need the full supplier object:

```js
var productSchema = new Schema({
   supplier: {
      _id: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Supplier' },
      name: String
   }
});
```

That enables you to do something like:

```js
Product.findById(id).populate('supplier._id').exec(err, product) {
    // product.supplier._id is the full Supplier doc instead of just the _id
});
```

Comment: I haven't had the chance to read about ref until now. If there are some nice things that this technique can do, can you point out some, sO I can choose this as the answer, thanks!